# mySQL data range into a 0/1 flag for individual date

Tags: mysql

I've got two tables:

t

```
ID   | date       | flag
1    | 2014-08-20 | 0
1    | 2014-08-21 | 0
1    | 2014-08-23 | 0
1    | 2014-08-25 | 0
1    | 2014-08-28 | 0
2    | 2014-08-24 | 0
```

u

```
ID   | date_from  | date_to
1    | 2014-08-20 | 2014-08-22 
1    | 2014-08-27 | 2014-08-28 
2    | 2014-08-27 | 2014-08-28
```

I want to put '1' into flag column if the date in the table t is within the range of the dates from the table u. Of course for each individual ID.

So I want in this case:

```
ID   | date       | flag
1    | 2014-08-20 | 1
1    | 2014-08-21 | 1
1    | 2014-08-23 | 0
1    | 2014-08-25 | 0
1    | 2014-08-28 | 1
2    | 2014-08-24 | 0
```

I tried all of the examples I could found but the only result I could manage to work was adding '1' if the date from table t was found in any of the ranges in the table u and not the exact one for the desired ID. So the flag column was filled with '1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join it with a left join (all rows from the left table), then check if an entry in the joined table is present. If yes, return 1, else 0.

```
select
t.*,
if(u.id is null, 0, 1) as my_flag
from
t
left join u on t.date between u.date_from and u.date_to
```

You can also turn this into an update statement:

```
update
t
left join u on t.date between u.date_from and u.date_to
set t.flag = if(u.id is null, 0, 1);
```

Comment: That's what I was missing in the first place - on t.date between u.date_from and u.date_to. Great answer. Thanks, working like a charm :)

Comment: You can juse use `(u.id is not null)` as my_flag.  The `if()` is not necessary.